# Windows store xaml add button with click event handler to gridviewitem

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I have a gridView the data is coming from a datasource.

How can i add a button to a gridviewitem datatemplate and add a click event handler to the button?

Comment: Are you using a view model?

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: @MattBall While I agree that the poster needs to include more information about what they've tried and what their situation is, this is actually a legitimately difficult question for someone new to XAML (hard to see that if you aren't familiar with XAML though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you genuinely need to have a button in your `ItemTemplate` - the easiest way to add an event handler is to create a `UserControl` for use in the `ItemTemplate`, put the button in it and add the event handler inside of that `UserControl`.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to accept an answer if you want to show appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to not actually use a Button at all and simply setting `IsItemClickEnabled` to `true` and using the [`ItemClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to do this is to bind the command of your button to a command property on the `DataContext` of the item which is templated.